# Separate FFT components into separate plots using MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, fft

I am hoping someone here can help. I have converted my signal via FFT to see the primary component/s. Like this:

[image: FFT]

I now want to separate that component, and other components, as given in another graph below in (c) to (d).

[image: Goal]

But I don’t know the code to do this? Does anyone know how they could be separated to plot separately?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can filter each harmonic with a bandpass filter, or you could synthesize them, since they seem to have a well-defined frequency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply MBaz. I know the fundamental frequencies would be fo, 2fo, 3fo, 4fo etc. So if I wanted just to plot the fundamental frequencies, please could you give me an idea of what the code would look like?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to find the frequency bands that you want and apply the filter on the original signal (time domain).

Another possibility (not so good) is to zero the FFT amplitudes that you don't want and then do IFFT (this is the matlab function). Remember that IFFF requires the double-sided Fourier representation with complex numbers.

Comment: Hi Filipe, thank you. But isn't that what the FFT has already done? Also, if you look at the black lines in Figure (c), some are below the blue and red, so I can't set to zero below a certain threshold.

Comment: The fourth chart seems to be obtained by segmenting FFT results and then IFFT. The third chart, I don't fully understand what is represented... It can be a time domain filtering, with band pass, followed by FFT.